# Using Time in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, timing

I rewriting a simple midi music sequencer from javascript into Python as a way of teaching myself Python.

I'm ready to begin working with time (for fireing midi events) but I can't find any good resources for executing scripts in time, scheduling timing events, etc.

A few things I've read suggest I should use a module like tkinter, but I would rather have all the timing mechanisms independent of any gui module.

Does anyone have any suggestions/resources for working with time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For executing scripts in a certain interval (of course within another script), you might want to take a look at the `time` module ([Documentation here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html)).

But if you are planning to use `timing` with a GUI, you might want to have concurrent threading or processing so that there is not delay with the user interface. In such case you can use `multithreading` ([Documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)) or `multiprocessing` ([Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)) modules.

As a final note, some GUI frameworks come with built-in threading support, so you might want to take a look at that. For example, `PyQT4` has something called `QThread` which handles all thread/event manipulation.